# LibgGdx - Load TrueTypeFont in AssetManager

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I am trying to load my `.ttf` fonts in my LibGdx `AssetManager` but I can't seem to get it right. What I tried:

Inside my AssetManager Class:

```
public static void load(){
//...
//Fonts
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
manager.load(fontTest, FreeTypeFontGenerator.class); //fontTest is a ttf-font
```

Then I try to use it like this in my Screen:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = GdxAssetManager.manager.get(GdxAssetManager.fontTest, FreeTypeFontGenerator.class);
params.size = 50;
font = generator.generateFont(params); //set the bitmapfont to the generator with parameters
```

This gives me a lot of weird errors. I dont even know where to look for faults. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is because they are not boeing loaded. Its kind of a bug or misleading design of that `FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader`. This is the way you need to do it to make it work:

```
// set the loaders for the generator and the fonts themselves
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

// load to fonts via the generator (implicitely done by the FreetypeFontLoader).
// Note: you MUST specify a FreetypeFontGenerator defining the ttf font file name and the size
// of the font to be generated. 
FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter size1Params = new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();            
size1Params.fontFileName = "ls-bold.otf";//name of file on disk
size1Params.fontParameters.size = ((int)((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.10f)));         
manager.load("fontWinFail.ttf", BitmapFont.class, size1Params);//BUGGY:We need to append .ttf otherwise wont work...just put any name here and append .ttf MANDATORY(this is the trick)
```

See the last line, you have to append .ttf to any random name you choose. That's the trick.

Now, the example you commented you want is like this:

```
BitmapFont                      fontWinFail; 
fontWinFail = manager.get("fontWinFail.ttf", BitmapFont.class);//notice same name used in above segment(NOTE that this is just a name, not the name of the file)         
fontWinFail.setColor(Color.BLACK);

//Then on your render() method
fontWinFail.draw(batch, "hello world", Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.5f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*0.6f);
```

Comment: Oh I have to do the paramaters there too, I see. Can you give me example code of how to assigne this to a BitmapFont that I would place on the Screen? Something like the second code example in my question

Comment: Usually you would take the name, in my case `fontTest` and use that to get the font from the AssetManager, but since here the name is `"fontTest.ttf"` Im not sure how to proceed. I cant do the normal `(GdxAssetManager.fontTest, BitmapFont.class)`

Comment: Thanks man, btw it work without the "name.extension" thing just fine :) But u helped me get in the right direction

Comment: Cool, your welcome. And it was a really good valid question that you posted, I was stuck when I had that same problem time ago.